# Pass out variable as a command in Crystal Reports connected to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I am trying to call a stored procedure using `command (writing query)` while connecting to Crystal Reports. Procedure has two `IN` parameters and one `Out` parameter which is a `Sys_Refcursor` to output the dataset from a table.

Problem is when calling the procedure from Crystal Reports I am getting error in setting the out variable.

```
call data_proc('abcd123', 345,:Data_Out)
```

above is my code from Crystal Reports.

Error:

> ORA-01008 not all variables are bound

Unable to cross this hurdle, if I directly call procedure from connections instead of query their is `User Name` dependency where user name is prefixed to procedure and when I deploy on other databases I need to manually update the connection.

Comment: Hi Siva. Please refrain from adding "Please help" begging to _all_ of your questions. It is quite unnecessary. Technical writing is an expectation here. Perhaps you think of this as a politeness, but some of your readers will just see it as needy pleading.

Comment: There is a popular view on Stack Overflow, which is that volunteers are happy to take problems and deliver it without any effort from the question author (it is not true, but it is believed anyway). The same group also believes that if they beg hard enough, they will get priority attention compared to folks who put only minimal effort into their begging.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: There is an optimistic phraseology that works very well when asking for volunteer help on the internet, and the key is to show readers that you have your own agency and that you are not affecting to be helpless. To do this, your question firstly needs to be answerable and specific. It also needs to invoke your own agency. So, "How can I fix this?" is a good start. "How can I foo the bar in Widget Reports?" is better, since it is more specific. [Read more in the answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391945).

Comment: @halfer sure thanks for suggestion, Though my intentions are different but if it really conveys different meaning in a forum will refrain from using the sentences that are not needed.

Comment: Yes please. Thanks Siva!